# How To UnitTest Combine Cancellables?

Tags: swift

> How to write unit test for this func loadDemos()?
>
> Here is the code

```
class BenefitViewModel: ObservableObject {

func loadDemos()  {
            let testMode =  ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.contains("testMode")
            if testMode {
                self.demos = DummyData().decodeDemos()
            } else {
                cancellables.insert(self.getDemos().sink(receiveCompletion: { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        break
                    case .finished:
                        break
                    }
                }, receiveValue: { response in
                    self.demos = response
                    print(“Demos: \(response.count)")
                }))
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is it that you want to test?

Comment: I would like to make sure the Demos:  response.count > 0

Comment: Ok so you just mock `getDemos` and do a normal async test.

Comment: @matt, getDemos() returns this type AnyPublisher<DemoObjectType, APIError>, I have the demoObject that is DemoObjectType, how can I mock getDemos?

Comment: I assume that `getDemos` actually performs some networking. You always need to mock the network for purposes of testing; there is no point accidentally testing the real network! So you would have a version of `getDemos` that just returns a Just or similar so that we bypass the network. Then, as I said, your code is still async, so your test would use an Expectation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At the risk of being a little annoying, I'm going to answer the more general version of your question: how can you unit test a Combine pipeline?

Let's step back and start with some general principles about unit testing:

- Don't test Apple's code. You already know what it does. Test *your* code.
- Don't test the network (except in a rare test where you just want to make sure the network is up). Substitute your own class that behaves like the network.
- Asynchronous code needs asynchronous testing.

I assume your `getDemos` does some asynchronous networking. So without loss of generality I can illustrate with a different pipeline. Let's use a simple Combine pipeline that fetches an image URL from the network and stores it in a UIImage instance property (this is intended to be quite parallel to what you are doing with your pipeline response and `self.demos`). Here's a naive implementation (assume that I have some mechanism for calling `fetchImage`):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var image : UIImage?
    var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    func fetchImage() {
        let url = URL(string:"https://www.apeth.com/pep/manny.jpg")!
        self.getImageNaive(url:url)
    }
    func getImageNaive(url:URL) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .compactMap { UIImage(data:$0.data) }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { completion in
                print(completion)
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] image in
                print(image)
                self?.image = image
            }
            .store(in: &self.storage)
    }
}
```

All very nice, and it works fine, but it isn't testable. The reason is that if we simply call `getImageNaive` in our test, we will be testing the network, which is unnecessary and wrong.

So let's make this testable. How? Well, in this simple example, we just need to break off the asynchronous publisher from the rest of the pipeline, so that the test can substitute its own publisher that doesn't do any networking. So, for example (again, assume I have some mechanism for calling `fetchImage`):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // Output is (data: Data, response: URLResponse)
    // Failure is URLError
    typealias DTP = AnyPublisher <
        URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output,
        URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Failure
    >
    var image : UIImage?
    var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    func fetchImage() {
        let url = URL(string:"https://www.apeth.com/pep/manny.jpg")!
        self.getImage(url:url)
    }
    func getImage(url:URL) {
        let pub = self.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
        self.createPipelineFromPublisher(pub: pub)
    }
    func dataTaskPublisher(for url: URL) -> DTP {
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    func createPipelineFromPublisher(pub: DTP) {
        pub
            .compactMap { UIImage(data:$0.data) }
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { completion in
                print(completion)
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] image in
                print(image)
                self?.image = image
            }
            .store(in: &self.storage)
    }
}
```

You see the difference? It's almost the same, but the pipeline itself is now distinct from the publisher. Our method `createPipelineFromPublisher` takes as its parameter *any* publisher of the correct type. This means that we have abstracted out the use of `URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher`, and can substitute our *own* publisher. In other words, `createPipelineFromPublisher` is testable!

Okay, let's write the test. My test case contains a method that generates a "mock" publisher that simply publishes some Data wrapped up in the same publisher type as a data task publisher:

```
func dataTaskPublisherMock(data: Data) -> ViewController.DTP {
    let fakeResult = (data, URLResponse())
    let j = Just<URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Output>(fakeResult)
        .setFailureType(to: URLSession.DataTaskPublisher.Failure.self)
    return j.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

My test bundle (which is called CombineTestingTests) also has an asset catalog containing a UIImage called `mannyTesting`. So all I have to do is call ViewController's `createPipelineFromPublisher` with the data from that UIImage, and check that the ViewController's `image` property is now that same image, right?

```
func testImagePipeline() throws {
    let vc = ViewController()
    let mannyTesting = UIImage(named: "mannyTesting", in: Bundle(for: CombineTestingTests.self), compatibleWith: nil)!
    let data = mannyTesting.pngData()!
    let pub = dataTaskPublisherMock(data: data)
    vc.createPipelineFromPublisher(pub: pub)
    let image = try XCTUnwrap(vc.image, "The image is nil")
    XCTAssertEqual(data, image.pngData()!, "The image is the wrong image")
}
```

Wrong! The test fails; `vc.image` is `nil`. What went wrong? The answer is that Combine pipelines, even a pipeline that starts with a Just, are asynchronous. Asynchronous pipelines require asynchronous testing. My test needs to *wait* until `vc.image` is *not* `nil`. One way to do that is with a predicate that watches for `vc.image` to no longer be `nil`:

```
func testImagePipeline() throws {
    let vc = ViewController()
    let mannyTesting = UIImage(named: "mannyTesting", in: Bundle(for: CombineTestingTests.self), compatibleWith: nil)!
    let data = mannyTesting.pngData()!
    let pub = dataTaskPublisherMock(data: data)
    vc.createPipelineFromPublisher(pub: pub)
    let pred = NSPredicate { vc, _ in (vc as? ViewController)?.image != nil }
    let expectation = XCTNSPredicateExpectation(predicate: pred, object: vc)
    self.wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 10)
    let image = try XCTUnwrap(vc.image, "The image is nil")
    XCTAssertEqual(data, image.pngData()!, "The image is the wrong image")
}
```

And the test passes! Do you see the point? The system-under-test here is exactly the right thing, namely, the mechanism that forms a pipeline that receives the output that a data task publisher *would* emit and sets an instance property of our view controller. We have tested *our code* and *only* our code. And we have demonstrated that our pipeline works correctly.

Comment: Oh, my,  I just saw this! You nailed it! I was struggling with how to unit test the Combine pipeline!  @matt, I will checkout your books too! Thank you so much for dedicating yourself helping the beginners!

Comment: Which book of yours that you would suggest focusing on the Combine topic?

Comment: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/ but it doesn't talk about testing. Maybe I should add a section about that, not sure.

Comment: missing `return` in `func dataTaskPublisher(for url: URL) -> DTP` ?

Comment: @Laufwunder No, unless you're using a very old version of Swift.

Answer (score 0):

With @Joakim Danielson help on this question [How to convert myObject to AnyPublisher<myObject, Never>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66050438/how-to-convert-myobject-to-anypublishermyobject-never/66053430#66053430). I came up with this answer.

```
 func testDemoData() {
        let testDemoData = Just(demoData).eraseToAnyPublisher()
        
        cancellables.insert(testDemoData.sink(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] result in
                switch result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    XCTAssert(true)
                    print(error)
                    break
                case .finished:
                    break
                }
            }, receiveValue: { [weak self] response in
           
                XCTAssert((response!.count ) >= 0)
            
            }))
        }
```

Comment: That's cute but it is not testing what you said you wanted to test, namely the response count in `loadDemos`. This might be a trivial test that doesn't contact your real code at any point.

Comment: Ha ha.. Can you share an answer?

Comment: Well my comment tells you what I suggest.

Comment: @matt Can you please share answer? Or correct/edit my answer? I really don't understand your suggestions.