# How to convert myObject to AnyPublisher<myObject, Never>?

Tags: swift

I have an object named myObjectType, how do I convert myObjectType to AnyPublisher<myObjectType, Never> ?

```
   func getDemoTest() -> AnyPublisher<myObjectType, Never> {
        return ????????? ///How do I convert the myObjectType to the AnyPublisher<myObjectType, Never> ?
    }
```

Comment: There are many ways to do that but which is correct depends on the context. So you need to explain what you are trying to achieve, that is what is your data and what is it you want to publish?

Comment: I'm trying to unit test the cancellable. I need to convert myObjectType to AnyPublisher<myObjectType, Never>

Comment: `Just(someObject).eraseToAnyPublisher()`

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for!!! Please put in the answer and I will mark it as the answer! Thank so much for taking your time helping me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to create a one-time publisher is to use Just

```
Just(someObject).eraseToAnyPublisher()
```