# Reusable publishers (subscriptions?) in Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I've got a case where I'm using a `dataTaskPublisher` and then chaining the output, as shown below. Now I'm implementing a background download, using `URLSession`'s `downloadTask(with:completionHandler)` and I need to perform the exact same operations.

So everything in the code, below, from the `decode(type:decoder)` onwards is common between both situations. Is there some way I can take a `Data` object and let it be passed through that same set of steps without duplicating the code?

```swift
anyCancellable = session.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
  .map { $0.data }
  .decode(type: TideLowWaterHeightPredictions.self, decoder: Self.decoder)
  .map { $0.predictions }
  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  .sink {
    ...
  } receiveValue: { predictions in
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Sure but you need to split the pipeline into two pieces.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66056209/341994

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks @matt

Comment: Cool! Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it up in an extension:

```
extension Publisher where Output == Data {
    func gargoyle() -> AnyCancellable {
        return self
            .decode(type: TideLowWaterHeightPredictions.self, decoder: Self.decoder)
            .map { $0.predictions }
            .sink {
                ...
            } receiveValue: { predictions in
                ...
            }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
session
    .dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .map { $0.data }
    .gargoyle()
    .store(in: &tickets)
```

Or like this if you already have a `Data`:

```
Just(data)
    .gargoyle()
    .store(in: &tickets)
```