# Unit Testing Combine

Tags: swift, xctest, combine

I'm having difficulties testing Combine. I'm following:

- https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/unit-testing-combine-based-swift-code/

Which tests:

```swift
final class ViewModel {
    @Published private(set) var tokens = [String]()
    @Published var string = ""
 
    private let tokenizer = Tokenizer()

    init () {
        $string
            .flatMap(tokenizer.tokenize)
            .replaceError(with: [])
            .assign(to: &$tokens)
    }
}

struct Tokenizer {
    func tokenize(_ string: String) -> AnyPublisher<[String], Error> {
        let strs = string.components(separatedBy: " ")
        return Just(strs)
            .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

with the following:

```
func testTokenizingMultipleStrings() throws {
    let viewModel = ViewModel()
    let tokenPublisher = viewModel.$tokens
        .dropFirst()
        .collect(2)
        .first()
    viewModel.string = "Hello @john"
    viewModel.string = "Check out #swift"
    let tokenArrays = try awaitPublisher(tokenPublisher)
    XCTAssertEqual(tokenArrays.count, 2)
    XCTAssertEqual(tokenArrays.first, ["Hello", "john"])
    XCTAssertEqual(tokenArrays.last, ["Check out", "swift"])
}
```

And the following helper function:

```swift
extension XCTestCase {
    func awaitPublisher<T: Publisher>(
        _ publisher: T,
        timeout: TimeInterval = 10,
        file: StaticString = #file,
        line: UInt = #line
    ) throws -> T.Output {
        var result: Result<T.Output, Error>?
        let expectation = self.expectation(description: "Awaiting publisher")
        let cancellable = publisher.sink(
            receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .failure(let error):
                    result = .failure(error)
                case .finished:
                    break
                }
                expectation.fulfill()
            },
            receiveValue: { value in
                result = .success(value)
            }
        )
        waitForExpectations(timeout: timeout)
        cancellable.cancel()
        let unwrappedResult = try XCTUnwrap(
            result,
            "Awaited publisher did not produce any output",
            file: file,
            line: line
        )
        return try unwrappedResult.get()
    }
}
```

Here `receiveValue` is never called so the test doesn't complete.
How can I get this test to pass?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66056209/341994 might help.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and eventually realized that for the test to pass, we need to update the view-model **between** setting up the subscription and waiting for the expectation. Since both currently happen inside the `awaitPublisher` helper, I added a closure parameter to that function:

```swift
func awaitPublisher<T: Publisher>(
    _ publisher: T,
    timeout: TimeInterval = 10,
    file: StaticString = #file,
    line: UInt = #line,
    closure: () -> Void
) throws -> T.Output {
    ...
    let expectation = ...
    let cancellation = ...

    closure()

    waitForExpectations(timeout: timeout)
    ...
}
```

Note the exact position of the closure – it won’t work if it’s called too early or too late.

You can then call the helper in your test like so:

```swift
let tokenArrays = try awaitPublisher(publisher) {
    viewModel.string = "Hello @john"
    viewModel.string = "Check out #swift"
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the issue. I suggest change 
`closure: () -> Void` to `when perform: () -> Void` to follow *Given - When - Then* convention.

Answer (score 0):

```
    let viewModel = ViewModel()
    let tokenPublisher = viewModel.$tokens
        .dropFirst()
        .collect(2)
        .first()
    viewModel.string = "Hello @john"
    viewModel.string = "Check out #swift"
    let tokenArrays = try awaitPublisher(tokenPublisher)
```

Your `tokenPublisher` won't do anything until you subscribe to it.  In this code you create the publisher, do some actions that *would* have pushed values through the Publisher *if* anyone was subscribed to it, then you call `awaitPublisher` (the thing that does the subscription). You need to reverse those:

```
    let viewModel = ViewModel()
    let tokenPublisher = viewModel.$tokens
        .dropFirst()
        .collect(2)
        .first()
    let tokenArrays = try awaitPublisher(tokenPublisher)
    viewModel.string = "Hello @john"
    viewModel.string = "Check out #swift"
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I unfortunately didn't find the answers from the responses above helpful. Later, I discovered this [Swift Package](https://github.com/albertbori/TestableCombinePublishers), and it elegantly addressed our pain points.
This author save me a day.

Here are my example test function.

```swift
import Combine
import TestableCombinePublishers
import XCTest

func testCollect3Values() {
        let values = [0, 1, 2]
        let intValue = CurrentValueSubject<Int, Never>(-1)
        intValue.send(values[0])
        let test = intValue
            .collect(values.count) // 3
            .expect(values)        // [0, 1, 2]
            .expectNoCompletion()
        intValue.send(values[1])
        intValue.send(values[2])
        test.waitForExpectations(timeout: 1)
}
```